# Convergence in probability for two statistics of Laplace random variables

Tags: self-study, estimation, convergence, asymptotics, law-of-large-numbers

Suppose $X_i$ are iid random variables.  $X_i \sim \mathrm{Laplace}(\lambda)$.

Also define:
$$
U_n = \frac{1}{n-2}\sum_{i=1}^n{|X_i|}
$$
$$
V_n = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1}   \sum_{i=1}^n{X_i^2} }
$$

Given that $\rightarrow_p$ shows convergence in probability, we want to find $a$, $b$ such that: 
$$
U_n \rightarrow_p a, \quad V_n \rightarrow_p b
$$

Here are my thoughts: $|X_i|$ could considered as an exponential distribution variable. With that, $\sqrt{n} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n{|X_i|}  \rightarrow_p E|X_i|$ (weak law of large numbers). However this result does not seem to be very useful. Also we know that $\sum_{i=1}^n{|X_i|}$ has Gamma/Erlang distribution.

Comment: Are the $X_i$' independent? In this case, for the first question, you indeed get that $n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n|X_i|\to \mathbb E|X_1|$ for the weak law of large numbers. For the second case, you actually have to compute the limit in probability of $n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2$.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, but posting the hint here if anyone else wants to solve it. For $U_n$, first prove the probabilistic convergence of $Q_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n |X_i|$, and then using the fact that $U_n = \frac{n}{n-2}Q_n$ find the probabilistic convergence for $U_n$.

For $V_n$ use a similar trick.

Comment: But $U_n$ does *not* equal $\frac{n}{n-1}Q_n$. Look at your question again. The general form of the argument here is okay, but as specifically expressed it doesn't work for the $U_n$ that was defined in your question.

Comment: But $U_n \rightarrow_p Q_n $ as $n \rightarrow +\infty$. Isn't it enough to use the convergence result of $Q_n$ for $U_n$?

Comment: To repeat myself, *the general form of the argument is okay*. The problem is your statement $U_n = \frac{n}{n-1}Q_n$, which *given the definition of $U_n$ in your question* is simply untrue. Please look at how you defined $U_n$ in the question and compare it with the definition of $Q_n$ and the relation between $U$ and $Q$ your answer - the problem should be obvious. Either fix the question or the answer so that they correspond. It requires only a *single character change* in one or the other.

Comment: Oh I see! Sry. Corrected.

Comment: Thanks, that's better. If I hadn't already upvoted, I would.